# What do ARM revisions mean? e.g. r2p1

Tags: arm, cortex-m, documentation

## Questions

1. What do the "revisions" mean in the processor documentation at the ARM Information Center?
2. Do they refer to <strike>silicon</strike> processor core design revisions, documentation revisions, or something else?
3. What do the `r` and `p` stand for?

Please include a citation(s) if you can.

## Example

The [Cortex-M3 documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0438f/ch01s08s02.html) includes the following subsections:

- Revision: r2p1
- Revision: r2p0
- Revision: r1p1

Comment: "r" is for "revision". "p" is for "point".

Comment: ARM doesn't make silicon, so there's no silicon to revise.

Comment: @brhans, perhaps I should've said processor core design revisions?

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0438f/DDI0438F_cortex_a15_r3p1_trm.pdf#page=23